# How to use msi installer setexternalui with pascal

Tags: windows-installer, pascal

I have implemented a custom dialog with c/c++ and `winapi` for installing a msi package with `setexternalui` using `msi.dll/msi.h`. Now I want to port this dialog to free pascal due to the better gui abstraction. I could not find a way how to start a msi like I did before. It is not enough to just start the installer as an external process; I need to start it hidden and retrieve the current progress value via some kind of callback.

Are there pascal bindings for msi installer?

Comment: Not really. The one Marco writes about seems to be pretty old. You'll have to convert it yourself, or find one on the web. Note that this Q asks for a recommendation, and such questions are not really allowed.

Comment: I know this kind of question sucks, but as long as there is no better place to ask, I'll stick to stack overflow.

Comment: It is not that it "sucks", it is that the rules don't **allow** it and people may vote to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Free Pascal has a header for this unit called jwamsi, but it is older and might not be 64-bit proof YMMV.

Comment: If the name starts with *jwa*, it could be a *JEDI Windows API* conversion, and there could be a newer version -- although what I could find was from around 2008-2010.

Comment: Yes, they are jedi winapi headers. They have been synchronized for the time that jediapi was still in continous development, but contain FPC specific fixes (often 64-bit, FPC was earlier there, but mostly in more core headers). Jedi API had occasional fixes in SCL (or whatever) period that might not be merged